# Lowndes' apportionment

Tags: core-language, algorithm

I am trying to program Lowndes' apportionment but i got some problems.
Indeed the total of allocated seats is not equal to the disponible seats .

Here is my code

```
quota={0.287582, 2.54031, 8.17211};
seats= 11;
ql = IntegerPart[quota];
qll = Table[If[ql[[i]] == 0, ql[[i]] = ql[[i]] + 1 , q[i]], {i, Length[ql]}];
tl = qbl - ql /. x_ /; x < 0 -> 0;
  (*Attribue un quota de zéro au groupe auquel on a attribué un siège*)
sal = qll - seats;
zl = Table[{i, tl[[i]]}, {i, Length[tl]}];
gl = Sort[zl, #1[[2]] > #2[[2]] &];
del = Drop[gl, -(Length[ql] - sal)];
desl = Table[de[[i, 1]], {i, Length[del]}]
rrl = Table[ If[MemberQ[desl, i], ql[[i]] = ql[[i]] + 1,  ql[[i]]], {i, 1,  Length[gl]}]
```

Can someone help me ?

Comment: Sorry my fault ... I have chosen a wrong tag

Answer (score 5):

If I have understood Lowndes' method of apportionment (referencing [this link](http://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/convergence/apportioning-representatives-in-the-united-states-congress-lowndes-method-of-apportionment)), then I think your code is a lot more complicated than it needs to be.

I believe the following implements a solution:

```
statePop = {3.2, 27.9, 89.9};
seats = 11;

(*Assign each state its initial quota*)
stateQuota = Floor[seats statePop/Total[statePop]];

(*Assign the remaining seats by the fewest representatives per person*)
While[Total[stateQuota] < seats,
 idx = Position[#, Min[#]][[1, 1]] &@(stateQuota/statePop);
 stateQuota[[idx]]++;
]
```

The code should be quite self explanatory.